# asp.net stop button event running on Refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, page-refresh

I have a button that has click event in my C#. This works great. However afetr pressing F5 to refresh the page I noticed the button event is fired. This occurs every time I click F5. I've added if(page.IsPostBack) and the method still runs.

Is there any way to stop this method from firing when the F5 Refresh button is clicked?

Thanks!

http://pastebin.com/9ycNraaT

Comment: Could you add code with button declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a page that needs to be run once, you should implement logic in your code that prevents the same method from running multiple times. In pseudo-code:

```
if (canExecuteMethod()) {
    executeMethod();
} else {
    displayMessageThatMethodCannotBeExecuted();
}
```

For example, you can check a Session variable with `canExecuteMethod()`, which returns false when it is not present and is set in `executeMethod()`:

```
function canExecuteMethod() {
     return Session["methodIsExecuting"] == null 
         || Session["methodIsExecuting"] == false;
}

function executeMethod() {
    Session["methodIsExecuting"] = true;
    // ...
}
```

Of course the use of a Session variable has it limits, so you might want to consider using a database or AppSettings variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `Response.Redirect("Your page  ")`  after the your add/update code. it isn't good practice, but it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

if(!page.IsPostBack)

NOT if(page.IsPostBack)

Comment: This will not work as postback is set to true when the button is clicked and when refresh is clicked. I have found this method very useful though for binding on the prerender

Answer (score 0):

No way. If once you click button (and post data) after refresh the same data will be sended.